# Visual studio can file my debug dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

I build a dll called myLibd.dll , using the header myLib.h.
when trying to use the dll, I get an error message that 'myLib.dll was not found'.

It makes sense, since I build myLibd.dll and not myLib.dll.. but how can I tell visaul studio that it should use myLibd.dll and not myLib.dll?

I also tried to add myLibd.lib to 'Additional dependencies'. Didn't change a thing..

btw - if I create myLib.dll instead of myLibd.dll, all works fine.

Comment: Rename your myLibd.lib to myLib.lib :)

Comment: I dont have a myLib.lib  - since I create myLibd.dll, a myLibd.lib is created